# Is there a way to model table inheritance using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: inheritance, mysql-workbench, erd, single-table-inheritance

Is there a way to model table inheritance using MySQL Workbench?

I'd like the ERD to look similar to the left side of this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried first with sybase 15.2 and in mysql workbench just try 1:1 cardinality.
Connect Footballer and Player. It will give you name as primary key and foreign key. You might want to rename atribute because it will give you something like Player_name.